# Installing MySQL 5.6 on CentOS7

Tags: mysql, linux, centos

I am trying to install MySQL 5.6 on CentOS7. I have removed the mariadb-libs (as I need to use only MySQL) as they conflict with some libs of MySQL. I installed the missing perl module by yum install 'perl(Data::Dumper)'. The installation still does not work.
What am I missing? I get the following error:

```
rpm -Uhvvv MySQL-server-5.6.17-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64.rpm | more
D: ============== MySQL-server-5.6.17-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64.rpm
D: loading keyring from pubkeys in /var/lib/rpm/pubkeys/*.key
D: couldn't find any keys in /var/lib/rpm/pubkeys/*.key
D: loading keyring from rpmdb
D: opening  db environment /var/lib/rpm cdb:0x401
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages 0x400 mode=0x0
D: locked   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Name 0x400 mode=0x0
D:  read h#    1272 Header SHA1 digest: OK (e6870d8b02e1f67dee30779203c6104284ea269a)
D: added key gpg-pubkey-f4a80eb5-53a7ff4b to keyring
D: Using legacy gpg-pubkey(s) from rpmdb
D: Expected size:     86961692 = lead(96)+sigs(264)+pad(0)+data(86961332)
D:   Actual size:      5307336
D: MySQL-server-5.6.17-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64.rpm: Header SHA1 digest: OK (8a971c3546cc413fe949982ab3237a01f64ec0f3)
D:  added binary package [0]
D: found 0 source and 1 binary packages
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Conflictname 0x400 mode=0x0
D: ========== +++ MySQL-server-5.6.17-1.linux_glibc2.5 x86_64/linux 0x2
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Basenames 0x400 mode=0x0
D:  read h#      54 Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: OK
D:  Requires: /bin/sh                                       YES (db files)
D:  Requires: /bin/sh                                       YES (cached)
D:  Requires: /bin/sh                                       YES (cached)
D:  Requires: /bin/sh                                       YES (cached)
D:  Requires: /bin/sh                                       YES (cached)
D:  read h#      72 Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: OK
D:  Requires: /sbin/chkconfig                               YES (db files)
D:  read h#     313 Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: OK
D:  Requires: /usr/bin/perl                                 YES (db files)
D:  read h#     427 Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: OK
D:  Requires: /usr/sbin/groupadd                            YES (db files)
D:  Requires: /usr/sbin/useradd                             YES (db files)
D:  Requires: config(MySQL-server) = 5.6.17-1.linux_glibc2.5 YES (added provide)
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Providename 0x400 mode=0x0
D:  read h#     426 Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: OK
D:  Requires: coreutils                                     YES (db provides)
D:  read h#      77 Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: OK
D:  Requires: grep                                          YES (db provides)
D:  read h#     139 Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: OK
D:  Requires: libaio.so.1()(64bit)                          YES (db provides)
D:  Requires: libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.1)(64bit)                YES (db provides)
D:  Requires: libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.4)(64bit)                YES (db provides)
D:  read h#      51 Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: OK
D:  Requires: libc.so.6()(64bit)                            YES (db provides)
D:  Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)                 YES (db provides)
D:  Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit)                   YES (db provides)
D:  Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4)(64bit)                 YES (db provides)
D:  Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)(64bit)                   YES (db provides)
D:  Requires: libcrypt.so.1()(64bit)                        YES (db provides)
D:  Requires: libcrypt.so.1(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)             YES (db provides)
D:  Requires: libdl.so.2()(64bit)                           YES (db provides)
D:  Requires: libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)                YES (db provides)
D:  read h#       1 Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: OK
D:  Requires: libgcc_s.so.1()(64bit)                        YES (db provides)
D:  Requires: libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.0)(64bit)                 YES (db provides)
D:  Requires: libm.so.6()(64bit)                            YES (db provides)
D:  Requires: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)                 YES (db provides)
D:  Requires: libpthread.so.0()(64bit)                      YES (db provides)
D:  Requires: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)           YES (db provides)
D:  Requires: libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit)           YES (db provides)
D:  Requires: librt.so.1()(64bit)                           YES (db provides)
D:  Requires: librt.so.1(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)                YES (db provides)
D:  read h#      52 Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: OK
D:  Requires: libstdc++.so.6()(64bit)                       YES (db provides)
D:  Requires: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)(64bit)             YES (db provides)
D:  Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)(64bit)            YES (db provides)
D:  read h#     446 Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: OK
D:  Requires: procps                                        YES (db provides)
D:  Requires: rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1        YES (rpmlib provides)
D:  Requires: rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1       YES (rpmlib provides)
D:  Requires: rpmlib(VersionedDependencies) <= 3.0.3-1      YES (rpmlib provides)
D:  Requires: rtld(GNU_HASH)                                YES (db provides)
D: Obsoletes: MySQL-server-advanced                         NO  
D: Obsoletes: mysql-server < 5.6.17-1.linux_glibc2.5        NO  
D: Obsoletes: mysql-server-advanced                         NO  
D: Obsoletes: MySQL-server-classic                          NO  
D: Obsoletes: MySQL-server-community                        NO  
D: Obsoletes: MySQL-server-enterprise                       NO  
D: Obsoletes: MySQL-server-advanced-gpl                     NO  
D: Obsoletes: MySQL-server-enterprise-gpl                   NO  
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Obsoletename 0x400 mode=0x0
D: ========== recording tsort relations
D: ========== tsorting packages (order, #predecessors, #succesors, depth)
D:     0    0    0    1   +MySQL-server-5.6.17-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64
D: installing binary packages
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Obsoletename
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Conflictname
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Providename
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Basenames
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Name
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages
D: closed   db environment /var/lib/rpm
D: opening  db environment /var/lib/rpm cdb:0x401
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages (none) mode=0x42
D: sanity checking 1 elements
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Name (none) mode=0x42
D: running pre-transaction scripts
D: computing 192 file fingerprints
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Basenames (none) mode=0x42
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Group (none) mode=0x42
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Requirename (none) mode=0x42
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Providename (none) mode=0x42
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Conflictname (none) mode=0x42
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Obsoletename (none) mode=0x42
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Triggername (none) mode=0x42
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Dirnames (none) mode=0x42
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Installtid (none) mode=0x42
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Sigmd5 (none) mode=0x42
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Sha1header (none) mode=0x42
D: computing file dispositions
D: 0x0000fd01     4096      3494614     18243875 /
D: ========== +++ MySQL-server-5.6.17-1.linux_glibc2.5 x86_64-linux 0x2
D: Expected size:     86961692 = lead(96)+sigs(264)+pad(0)+data(86961332)
D:   Actual size:      5307336
D: MySQL-server-5.6.17-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64: Header SHA1 digest: OK (8a971c3546cc413fe949982ab3237a01f64ec0f3)
D:   install: MySQL-server-5.6.17-1.linux_glibc2.5 has 192 files
D: %pre(MySQL-server-5.6.17-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64): scriptlet start
D: %pre(MySQL-server-5.6.17-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64): execv(/bin/sh) pid 14403
Preparing...                          ########################################
+ '[' -x /usr/bin/my_print_defaults ']'
++ /usr/bin/my_print_defaults server mysqld
++ grep '^--datadir='
++ sed -n s/--datadir=//p
+ mysql_datadir=
++ /usr/bin/my_print_defaults server mysqld
++ grep '^--pid-file='
++ sed -n s/--pid-file=//p
+ PID_FILE_PATT=
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ mysql_datadir=/var/lib/mysql
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ PID_FILE_PATT='/var/lib/mysql/*.pid'
++ rpm -q --whatprovides mysql-server
+ installed='no package provides mysql-server'
+ '[' 1 -ne 0 -o -z 'no package provides mysql-server' ']'
++ rpm -q --whatprovides MySQL-server
+ installed='no package provides MySQL-server'
+ '[' 1 -eq 0 -a -n 'no package provides MySQL-server' ']'
++ ls -1 '/var/lib/mysql/*.pid'
++ wc -l
+ NR_PID_FILES=0
+ case $NR_PID_FILES in
+ SERVER_TO_START=
+ STATUS_FILE=/var/lib/mysql/RPM_UPGRADE_MARKER
+ '[' -f /var/lib/mysql/RPM_UPGRADE_MARKER ']'
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ NEW_VERSION=5.6.17-1.linux_glibc2.5
+ '[' -d /var/lib/mysql/mysql ']'
+ '[' -x /etc/init.d/mysql ']'
+ /etc/init.d/mysql stop
+ echo 'Giving mysqld 5 seconds to exit nicely'
+ sleep 5
Giving mysqld 5 seconds to exit nicely
D: %pre(MySQL-server-5.6.17-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64): waitpid(14403) rc 14403 status 0
D: ========== Directories not explicitly included in package:
D:          0 /etc/init.d/
D:          1 /etc/logrotate.d/
D:          2 /etc/
D:          3 /usr/bin/
D:          4 /usr/lib64/mysql/
D:          5 /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/
D:          6 /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/debug/
D:          7 /usr/sbin/
D:          8 /usr/share/doc/
D:         10 /usr/share/man/man1/
D:         11 /usr/share/man/man8/
D:         12 /usr/share/
D: ==========
D: create     100755  1 (   0,   0) 10815 /etc/init.d/mysql;53e50cd1
Updating / installing...
D: create     100644  1 (   0,   0)   844 /etc/logrotate.d/mysql;53e50cd1
D: create     100755  1 (   0,   0)4726596 /usr/bin/innochecksum;53e50cd1
D: create     100755  1 (   0,   0)4666133 /usr/bin/my_print_defaults;53e50cd1
D: create     100755  1 (   0,   0)6778320 /usr/bin/myisam_ftdump;53e50cd1
D: create     100755  1 (   0,   0)7194676 /usr/bin/myisamchk;53e50cd1
GZDIO:     304 reads, 18291337 total bytes in 0.110334 secs
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/bin/myisamchk;53e50cd1: cpio: read failed - Inappropriate ioctl for device
error: MySQL-server-5.6.17-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64: install failed
D: running post-transaction scripts
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Sha1header
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Sigmd5
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Installtid
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Dirnames
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Triggername
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Obsoletename
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Conflictname
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Providename
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Requirename
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Group
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Basenames
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Name
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages
D: closed   db environment /var/lib/rpm
MySQL-server-5.6.17-1.linux_glibc2.5  ########################################
```

Answer (score 1):

Dunno if you're still looking for a solution to this .. but just came across your question whilst looking for the same answer ... thought I'd drop this here ..

http://sharadchhetri.com/2014/07/31/how-to-install-mysql-server-5-6-on-centos-7-rhel-7/